# How do I make a loop in R that uses a different variable each time it loops?

Tags: r, loops

I want to make a loop that uses a different variable each time the loop repeats. Let's say I have 3 different variables: x, y, and z:

```
x <- 1
y <- 2
z <- 3
```

I want to perform the same calculation on x, y, and z. I want to multiply by 2:

```
B <- A*2
```

Before each loop, I want A to be set equal to the new variable. The long way to do this would be to write it all out manually:

```
A <- x
B <- A*2
A <- y
B <- A*2
A <- z
B <- A*2
```

I want to the result to be a vector of this form.

`C <- c(2,4,6)`

My calculation and variables are much longer than the ones I've shown here, so writing it out manually would make my code very messy. I would prefer to use a loop so I only have to write the calculation once.

Comment: Check out `help("mapply")` as in `mapply('*', list(x, y, z), list(2))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often you can avoid loops by storing things in a list and calling a function from the `apply` family:

```
mylist <- list(x, y, z)
sapply(mylist, function(x) x*2)
```

Notice that this is simple and useful if your variables are in a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
sapply(df, function(x) x*2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basic R programming, and can be solved with a form of `*apply`.

Start by putting your variables in a `list`.

```
x <- 1
y <- 2
z <- 3

my_list <- list(x, y, z)
```

First, the `mapply` in my comment. It's not strictly necessary to assign a new function, this is just to use a function, `f`, that *looks* like a function. The function `'*'` does not.

```
f <- `*`    # assign the function '*' to function f

mapply(f, my_list, list(2))
#[1] 2 4 6
```

Another way would be to use `lapply` or `sapply`. Read the help page (it's the same for both these forms of `*apply`).

```
g <- function(v){
    2*v
}

sapply(my_list, g)
#[1] 2 4 6

lapply(my_list, g)
```